# Kotlin: smart cast with multiple types

Tags: kotlin

I'm building a CST to AST mapper for antlr so I have tons of `*Context` classes that I need to map to their coresponding AST nodes.
I have ANTLR-produced classes and my mapper methods:

```
// Demo data:
open class Super
class Sub0: Super
class Sub1: Super
// Mappers:
fun map(a: Super) = println("Super")
fun map(a: Sub0) = println("Sub0")
fun map(a: Sub1) = println("Sub1")
```

Then, I'd like to use it as following:

```
listOf(Super(), Sub0(), Sub1()).forEach {
    when (it) {
        is B, is C -> { print('*'); map(it) }
        else -> map(it)
    }
}
```

I'd expect `it` to be smart-casted to either Sub0 or Sub1 and call the correct `map`, that however gives:

```
Super
*Super
*Super
```

Which indicates that it chose the right path but didn't do the auto-cast.
This approach works but gets really long as you have more and more `SubX`'s:

```
when (it) {
    is Sub0 -> {
        print("*");
        map(it)
    }
    is Sub1 -> {
         print("*");
         map(it)
    }
    else -> map(it)
}
```

I know I could use some black-magic in form of reflection and iterate over all `map(X)`s and then use some "clever trick" to choose the right one, but I'd rather not. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The smart cast does not work because the code inside the when branch `is B, is C -> map(it)` is type-checked only once. It is not compiled to two different sets of instructions, for one type and the other. The compiler needs to infer a single type for `it` that will work in both cases.

Neither of `Sub0` and `Sub1` can be chosen for the type of `it`, because choosing one of them does not cover the other. So the compiler chooses the least common supertype of `Sub0` and `Sub1`, which is `Super`. Then the call to `map` is resolved with statically-known type `Super` for `it`.

So indeed, splitting the branches so that only a single type is mentioned in the branch conditions is the way you can fix this.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. Is there any other way to do this than naming every possible subtype the class has (other than using reflection)?

Comment: As an alternative, you can merge the `map` functions into one and place a `when` statement inside. Then you will be able to group the branches wherever a common action needs to be done for different subtypes. Note that you'll face the same restriction if `map` needs to call another function with multiple overloads accepting different types. In that case, you can merge those overloads into a single function, too, and so on. I'm not sure what code structure is more suitable for your particular case as I'm not aware what exactly is the overall logic.

Comment: Yea, that's where I'm now. I guess it's not that terrible fate to name every one of them, thanks for the help!